# Can I decompile a Python program compiled with cx_freeze or py2exe?

Tags: python, decompiler

I recently accidentally installed a copy of Ubuntu over my copy of Windows and lost all my files. (Including all of my code files). I was wondering if I could somehow reverse the conversion that cx_Freeze/py2exe did so I would have my .py files back. Is this possible at all? (I used the modules tkinter and pygame.)

Comment: How do you accidentally install an operating system? cx_Freeze packs pyc files in a zip file (or a zip file appended to an exe). Unzip the file (or th exe), then use a python decompiler.

Comment: @Seth My trackpad was being tricky and I selected the LVM security installation or whatever it was without releasing it would delete my operating system. I stopped it when it told me it would delete the OS, but Windows no longer boots.

Comment: maybe just get your files back by reinstalling the windows boot loader?

Comment: @Dschoni How would I go about that?

Comment: That's outside the scope of this side. You can find help here:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/149674/how-to-create-or-recover-windows-bootloader-after-deleting-ubuntu-boot-drive

Comment: Or here:http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/33433/restore-the-windows-boot-loader-after-an-ubuntu-update/